# Python Construir um grafico parabola multiplas com matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou tentando fazer o grafico da figura, mas apenas a linha vermelha que é uma parabola multilpla. Faz parte de uma rede neural que eu tenho pronta, mas nao consigo gerar a funcao que gera essa parabola. É mais uma ajuda matematica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: VOcê já tem o código inicial - criando a série de números e chamando a função de plot? 
Fica mais fácl te ajudar, em vez de ter que criar o programa todo - e é o mais norma também - pedir ajuda sobre elementos pontuais de um programa, em vez de "como faz isso?" - deixando todo o trabalho para quem quiser te ajudar.

Comment: @jsbueno Está certo. Vou postar o código todo e a parte que não sei

Comment: a parte que está faltando é mais ou menos o que tem no "hello world" do matplotlb - então não incomodou tanto nesse caso - mas tenha em mente para as próximas questões.

Answer (score 1):

Para construir parábolas eu gosto de utilizar [função exponencial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_exponencial_natural), basicamente sua parábola é uma [função gaussiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), pq eu gosto de função exponencial `(exp)`? simplesmente pq eu consigo controlar onde a parábola será centrada além de controlar a largura da janela... para demonstrar eu criei um vetor `(dados)` de tamanho `1200`, em algumas posições adicionei "picos"

```
dados = np.zeros(1200)

dados[70] = 0.9
dados[290] = 0.9
dados[505] = 0.9
dados[720] = 0.9
dados[1000] = 0.9
```

Todo o resto do vetor é composto de zeros, plot do vetor `dados`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então agora eu quero inserir uma parábola em cada um desses picos...

criei um vetor auxiliar para me ajudar a encontrar o valor exponencial relativo da parábola:

```
x= np.linspace(0, 1, len(dados))
```

o Vetor é espaçado por `1` e possui o mesmo tamanho do vetor de entrada, agora vem a parte legal da brincadeira, criar a parábola nas posições dos picos do plot acima:

```
np.exp(-np.power(x - pos, float(2.)) / (2 * np.power(lenKernel, float(2.))))
```

A função acima calcula uma Função gaussiana(parábola):

```
x=vetor auxiliar
lenKernel=largura da janela
pos=posição onde a parábola será centrada
```

Agora você pode somar essa função para cada pico necessário, a saída do meu código produz o seguinte plot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



dados = np.zeros(1200)

dados[70] = 0.9
dados[290] = 0.9
dados[505] = 0.9
dados[720] = 0.9
dados[1000] = 0.9

lenKernel =0.020

y=0;

x= np.linspace(0, 1, len(dados))

for i in [(70), (290), (505), (720), (1000)]:
        pos=i/float(len(dados))
        y=np.exp(-np.power(x - pos, float(2.)) / (2 * np.power(lenKernel, float(2.)))) + y






plt.plot(dados)

plt.plot(y)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Gráficos no matplotlib requerem séries numéricas já preenchidas em um array do NumPy  -

Então, você pode escrever uma função que só se preocupa com a parte matemática mesmo, tomando um 'x' por entrada, e gerando um 'y' que funcione nos intervalos desejados, e aí é fácil preencher a série numérica com o numpy usando sua função.

Então, pensando na função - você quer que a intervalos periódicos sejam criadas "parabolas de ponta cabeça" com uma abertura estreita, e que abaixo de um certo limiar para os valores da parábola, o valor da função seja constante.

Interessante aí é que a função então não vai receber só "x" e te dar um "y"- ela tem valores de configuração - uma forma de fazer isso é uma função dentro de outra - a de fora recebe os parâmetros de "limiar", "intervalo" e "abertura" - e a de dentro é uma função que só recebe uma ordenada "x" e retorna "y". Isso não seria "necessário" - dá pra fazer com uma função só normal que receba x e mais os outro três parâmetros - mas aí , tem que colocar alguma logica extra na hora de gerar os valores de "y" - já que as formas de fazer isso com numpy normalmente assumem só um parâmetro.

então vamos ter algo da forma:

```
def parametrizar(periodo=100, limite=0, abertura=20):
    def f_x(x):
        # código que usa os 3 parâmetros acima para realmente calcular y
        ...
        return resultado
    return f_x
```

Agora, quanto a função em si - primeiro o mais fácil de resolver parece ser o "período" - basta pegar o resto da divisão de x pelo período desejado - mas percebo que além disso será legal ter um deslocamento também - então se o primeiro pico deseado for em "50" com um período de 200, normalizamos esses valores - de forma que o centro da parábola seja em "50" e tomamos o resto da divisão por "200" - fazendo passo a passo:

```
def parametrizar(deslocamento=50, periodo=100, deslocamento_y=1, limite=0.0, abertura=6):
    limite = float(limite)
    def f_x(x):
        # repete valores de x períodicamente:
        x1 = x % periodo
        # deixa que a abcissa seja '0' onde desejamos o pico
        x2 = x1 - deslocamento
        # escala o valor "x" antes de elevar ao quadrado de forma
        # que os valores para "abertura" sejam mais razoaveis:
        x3 = x2 / periodo

        # calcula a parábola em si:
        y = - abertura * (x3 * x3) + deslocamento_y
        # limita os valores baixos ao patamar desejado:
        if y < limite:
             y = limite 
        return y
    return f_x
```

E isso funciona.
Agora basta criar um array com os números y, e usar np.vectorize para aplicar a função  - e os parâmetros pdem ser modificados até que o plot final seja apropriado para o que você precisa:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = np.arange(0, 500,0.1, dtype=np.float64)

fx = parametrizar(abertura=30, limite=0.5)
y = np.vectorize(fx)(x)

plt.plot(x, y); plt.show()
```